# SqlCipher: Could not open database on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, sqlcipher, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

Previously I was using just SQLite and never had a problem, I just change to SQLCipher and on devices with versions 7, 8, 8.1, 9 its working fine, just with Android 6.0.1 I have the following error:

```
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: error code 14: Could not open database
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabaseInternal(SQLiteDatabase.java:2575)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1243)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1210)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1182)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1131)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1332)
    at android.xdl.dripapp_opencv.DB.DBSettings.InitializeDatabase(DBSettings.java:41)
    at android.xdl.dripapp_opencv.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:109)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6262)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

I'm using the following method to create the database, it's being called on onCreate method of my MainActivity:

**DBSettings**

```
public void InitializeDatabase(){
    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(_ctx);

    String databasePath = _ctx.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_FILE_NAME).getPath();

    SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databasePath, DATABASE_PASS, null);

    database.execSQL(CREATE_PATIENT_RECORDS_TABLE);
    database.execSQL(CREATE_SESSION_RECORDS_TABLE);


    database.close();
}
```

I have the following permission on Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I've even tried to ask for that permission at runtime as other answers says, but did not work, I got the dialog, after I accept the permission the same error appears.

I've tried to use not the path but the file, I got the same error:

```
File databaseFile = getDatabasePath(DATABASE_FILE_NAME);
SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, DATABASE_PASS, null);
```

I've tried to use `mkdir` as the documentation site for SQLCipher says, but nothing.

```
File databaseFile = getDatabasePath(DATABASE_FILE_NAME);
databaseFile.mkdirs();
```

I'm using this version of SQLCipher:

```
implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.2.0@aar'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging into the [SqlCipher Tests Project](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests) after running all test successfully on my 6.0.1 devices, found out the way the say on the documentation and the way the implemented is different.

What is working now is:

```
databaseFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

Instead of:

```
databaseFile.mkdirs();
```